# Sending an excel file to teams bot in a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have made a teams bot using botbuilder SDK 4.0, there is a feature in the bot where the user uploads a file to the bot and the bot collects the download_url and send it to the backend for the file to be downloaded and processed,this is all working fine until i added the bot to a channel.

I can send and receive messages from the bot without any problems but the file upload is not working the file can be uploaded in the channel but the bot does not receive the response and the 'context.activity.attachment.length' is 0, indicating that the bot has not received the attachment.

```
const url = context.activity.attachments[0].content.downloadUrl;
```

This is the code i use to get the download url after checking if the attachment.length is greater than 0.

Would appreciate any help in getting the download url for the file uploaded in the teams bot framework.

Comment: The issue might be due to the fact that file uploads in Teams are handled differently in personal chats and in channels. In a one-to-one chat, the file is sent as an attachment to the bot. However, in a channel, when a file is uploaded, it's actually stored in the SharePoint site associated with the team, and not sent as an attachment to the bot. This is why context.activity.attachments.length is 0.

Comment: Hi, @Sayali-MSFT, If that is the case how would i be able to get the attachment's content url?

Comment: Could you please look into this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-file-upload/csharp

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, I have looked at this sample before. Unfortunately , i can't run the sample bc i don't have an azure subscription. 
but from what i have gathered from the sample, by looking through the code , it is implementing the same method used to get the attachment in a teams personal chat.
My problem is to get the attachment uploaded in a TEAMS CHANNEL.

Answer (score 0):

Teams bot APIs work only in the personal context. They don't work in the channel or groupchat context.

**There are two ways to send files to and receive files from a bot:**

**Use the Microsoft Graph APIs:** This method works for bots in all Microsoft Teams scopes:

personal

channel

groupchat

**Use the Teams bot APIs:** These only support files in personal context.

**Reference doc link:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4#use-the-teams-bot-apis